# Why I am able to modify private data of base class from derieved class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here class d inherits class b. Since it's visibility is public so it can access public members of class b.

When I am creating newd, an object of d. there is no memory created for a (private data member of class b)

But still I am able to do get and set on that member using object of class d.

Can you please explain why this works. Also when is memory for a is allocated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class b{
    int a;
  public:
    void get(){
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    void set(int x){
        a = x;
    }
};

class d: public b{
    int c;
   public:
    void getac(){
        get();
        cout << c << endl;
    }
    void setc(int x, int y){
        set(x);
        c = y;
    }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    d newd;
    newd.setc(10, 20);
    newd.getac();
    newd.setc(12, 22);
    newd.getac();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you are not accessing `a` in `d` anywhere? You are accessing `void set(int)`, which is public.

Comment: Yes, But when memory for newd is allocated. for 'a' it will not allocate. Then how is this working.

Comment: Visibility and access (`public`, `protected`, and `private`) are about **names**, not the things that the names refer to. You cannot use the name `c` from outside of your class `b`, but that doesn't mean that the `int` named `c` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I am creating newd, an object of d. there is no memory created for a (private data member of class b)

That is wrong. A `d` is a `b`, and thus it has all members of `b`, and they take up memory. The total size of `d` is the size of `b` plus the size of the new members introduced by `d`. The `newd` object you created does have the `a` member (`newd.a`.) It just happens to be private and thus you don't have direct access to it. It doesn't mean it's not there.

You can verify this for yourself:

```
std::cout << "Size of b: " << sizeof(b)
          << ", size of d: " << sizeof(d) << '\n';
```

This will show you that `d` is larger than `b`, because it has both the `b::a` member **and** the `d::c` member.

Answer (score 2):

You suffer from a misunderstanding how member access scoping works.

This statement of yours:

> When I am creating newd, an object of d. there is no memory created for a (private data member of class b)

**is wrong**.

Access specifiers have nothing to do with memory or memory protections. When you derive from a class, **all** the class members of parent classes must be created as well. That is, because public and protected methods of the parent class still may be called, and may access their class' private members.

Answer (score 1):

Private means it can only be changed by methods declared in the same class. Your subclass is modifying that private field via a public method in that class. In other words, private data CAN be indirectly modified by functions outside that class. It just cannot be directly modified.